# Subgroups of finite index of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $H$ be a subgroup of index $n$ in $(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)\times \mathbb Z.$

> Is there finitely many subgroups of finite index of  $(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)\times \mathbb Z$ ?

If yes, can we find all the explicit forms possible  of the subgroup $H$  ?

thanks.

Comment: Take a look at Goursat's lemma.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every subgroup where there is an element with a nonzero right coordinate will have finite index, since $\langle (0,n) \rangle$ and $\langle (0,2n) \rangle \subseteq \langle (1,n) \rangle$ both would have finite index in the group, so we have there are infinitely many subgroups of finite index.

There are finitely many subgroups of a given index $n\in \mathbb N$, and I will show which subgroups further in the post, but I would like to point out all finitely generated groups have finitely many subgroups of a given index $n \in \mathbb{N}$. The sketch of how you would show that for finitely generated groups is: there are finitely many transitive actions on a finite set which can all be seen as $G$ acting on $G/H$ for some $H$ of finite index (and $G$ always has a transitive action on $G/H$), but all transitive finite actions have an associated group homomorphism $G \to S_n$, which determine $H$, and there are only finitely many since a group homomorphism is determined by where its generating set is mapped to and we are assuming there are finitely many generators.

Lets describe the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}/ 2\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$:

- Obviously if there is no nonzero element in the right coordinate of any element of $H \leq \mathbb{Z}/ 2\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ we have the subgroup $H$ is either trivial or $\mathbb Z/2 \mathbb Z \times \{0\}$ which is infinite index.
- Subgroups generated by one element are of the form $\{0\} \times n \mathbb{Z}$  or $\langle (1,n) \rangle$ have index $2n$.
- Subgroups $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times n\mathbb{Z}$ are of index $n$ and are generated by two elements. Not that if $(1,0)$ is in a subgroup generated by two elements, then it is of the above form, since we can consider an element with the least positive right coordinate $n$, so $(1,n)$ or $(0,n)$, but in either case we have $(0,n)$ is in the group, and $(1,0), (0,n)$ generate $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times n\mathbb{Z}$.

Using the above "classification" we get for index $n$ odd, there is only only one subgroup, $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times n\mathbb{Z}$, and for $n$ even there are three, $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times 2n\mathbb{Z}$, $\{0\} \times n \mathbb{Z}$, and $\langle (1,n) \rangle$.

We will now prove there are no other subgroups:
Say that we have a subgroup $H$ which is rank greater than or equal to two and not $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times n \mathbb{Z}$, so $(1,0) \not \in H$. I will show such an $H$ does not exist. Let $(0,m)$ and $(1,n)$ have the least positive possible $m,n$ with the respective coordinates. We will show $(1,0) \in H$ or $H$ has rank 1 which will contradict our assumptions.

Note that the group generated by $(0,m)$ and $(1,n)$ will have $(0,\gcd(n,m))$ or $(1,\gcd(n,m))$, we will now consider these cases.

- If $(0,\gcd(n,m))$, then $\gcd(n,m)=m$, so $m|n$. Also $\gcd(n,m)=n$ since $n-m$ would have to be $0$ since $m|n$ but $(1,n)$ has the least such $n$. So we have $(1,m),(0,m)$ in the group, so $(1,0)$ is in the group, a contradiction.
- If $(1,\gcd(n,m) )=(1,n)$ then $n|m$. Consider $(0,m), (1,m-n), (0,m-2n)$: by assumption $m-2n \leq 0$, but then $(1,m-n)$ must be $(1,0)$ or $(1,n)$, since $n=\gcd(n,m) | m$, the first case is an immediate contradiction, so we must have $(0,m)=(0,2n)$, notice that $(0,m) \in \langle (1,n) \rangle$. Suppose $(0,p)$ or $(1,p)$ is in $H$ but not in $\langle (1,n) \rangle$ with $p>0$. Well then in the case of $(0,p)$ we must have $2kn \neq p>2n$. If $n \not \mid p$ then $(1,\gcd(n,p)) \in H$ or $(0,\gcd(n,p)) \in H$ and $\gcd(n,p) <n$ a contradiction. If $n | p$, then $p=(2k+1)n$, so $(-2kn,p-2kn)=(0,n)$ and $(1,0) \in H$ a contradiction. If it is $(1,p)$ then $2kn=p>n$
  (as otherwise $q=\gcd(n,p)<n$ and we would have $(1,q)$ or $(0,q)$, either would be a contradiction, or $(1,p) \in \langle (1,n) \rangle$ which is also a contradiction) but that leads to $(1,2kn)-(2k,2kn)=(1,0) \in H$, a contradiction. So there is no such $p$, but then $H$ actually had rank 1, a contradiction.

Comment: This proof was very much "by the seat of my pants", so is probably not as elegant as it could be, but the proof is elementary, using only elementary number theory.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer